# How can I calculate dynamic average of an Object value in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I have this data structure where scores is an array of 4 objects

```
export const scores = [
  { day: '1', Barcelona: 1, Real: 3, Valencia: 0},
  { day: '2', Barcelona: 4, Real: 6, Valencia: 3},
  { day: '3', Barcelona: 7, Real: 7, Valencia: 3},
  { day: '4', Barcelona: 7, Real: 8, Valencia: 6},
];
```

I want to calculate the average of the score for each team

For example the average of Barcelona is 4,75 in this data.

```
var res = scores.map(score => score.Barcelona).reduce((acc, score) => score + acc);

var total = scores.length

var average = res/total
```

This is a prototype i have done reproducing the problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/qecrh?fontsize=14

What i need is to make this calculation dynamically, depending on the team i select in the drop down.

I have two states `this.state.homeCity` and `this.state.awayCity` that i can reuse to calculate dynamically the average.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter the array based on the selected team. Sum all values and divide by the `length` of `scores`

```js
    const scores = [
      { day: '1', Barcelona: 1, Real: 3, Valencia: 0},
      { day: '2', Barcelona: 4, Real: 6, Valencia: 3},
      { day: '3', Barcelona: 7, Real: 7, Valencia: 3},
      { day: '4', Barcelona: 7, Real: 8, Valencia: 6},
    ]
    
    const calculateAverageByTeam = team =>{
        const total = scores.map(x=> x[team]).reduce((a,c) => a +c)
        return total / scores.length
    }
    
    const barcelona = calculateAverageByTeam('Barcelona')
    const real = calculateAverageByTeam('Real')
    const valencia = calculateAverageByTeam('Valencia')
    console.log(barcelona, real, valencia)
```

[image: Edit Recharts Examples]

Comment: if you are so kind to show me in the codesandbox i have provided i accept the answer

Comment: Updated the answer with the forked sandbox

Answer (score 4):

You can supply the team name from the dropdown and send it to a function to calculate the score average for that team:

```js
 const scores = [
  { day: '1', Barcelona: 1, Real: 3, Valencia: 0},
  { day: '2', Barcelona: 4, Real: 6, Valencia: 3},
  { day: '3', Barcelona: 7, Real: 7, Valencia: 3},
  { day: '4', Barcelona: 7, Real: 8, Valencia: 6},
];

function getAverageScore(scores, team){
 return  scores.reduce((sum, t) => sum + t[team], 0)/ scores.length;
}
console.log(getAverageScore(scores, "Barcelona"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with slight modification of your code and with support of dynamic values:

```js
const scores = [
  { day: '1', Barcelona: 1, Real: 3, Valencia: 0},
  { day: '2', Barcelona: 4, Real: 6, Valencia: 3},
  { day: '3', Barcelona: 7, Real: 7, Valencia: 3},
  { day: '4', Barcelona: 7, Real: 8, Valencia: 6},
];

const printAverage = function() {
  const avg = scores.reduce((acc, c) => acc + c[this.value], 0) / scores.length;
  console.log(avg);
}

document.getElementById("team").addEventListener("change", printAverage);
```

```html
<select id="team">
  <option value="Barcelona">Barcelona</option>
  <option value="Real">Real</option>
  <option value="Valencia">Valencia</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the sandbox code you provided. The fundamental solution is the use of the `obj[key]` property accessor, which allows for dynamic property selection. `score['Barcelona']` is the same as `score.Barcelona`, but because it takes a string, we can provide a variable instead, passing the value of the dropdown in.

```
  getTeamAverage = (team) => {
    const sum = scores.map(score => score[this.state[`${team}City`]])
    .reduce((acc, score) => score + acc);

    return sum / scores.length;
  }

  render() {
  const homeAverage = this.getTeamAverage('home');
  const awayAverage = this.getTeamAverage('away');
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="main">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-5 title-container" />
                <div className="col-xs-7 form-container">
                  Pick the team:
                  <select
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={this.handleChangeHomeCity}
                  >
                    {listItems}
                  </select>
                  <select
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={this.handleChangeAwayCity}
                  >
                    {listItems}
                  </select>
                  <p>Team 1:{this.state.homeCity}</p>
                  <p>Team 2:{this.state.awayCity}</p>
                  <p>Average Score Team 1: {homeAverage}</p>
                  <p>Average Score Team 2: {awayAverage}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```